# How to use a C++ object's member function as a C-style callback?

Tags: c++

I need to use an object instance function as a C-style callback without parameter, it can't be static because I need to access an instance variable and I can't modify the function using the callback.

The signature of the caller function is:

```
void attachInterrupt(uint32_t pin, void (*callback)(void), uint32_t mode);
```

Alas I can't use the capture list since it's a C-style only callback so the following won't work:

```
attachInterrupt(pin, [this]() { tracker(); }, mode);
```

I keep a static array of pointers to the object instances so I tried this:

```
static Actuator* actuator;
actuator = instance[index];
attachInterrupt(pin, [] { actuator->tracker(); }, mode);
```

The problem is that all the lambda functions share the same reference to the pointer stored in actuator but I need that each lambda function use it's specific pointer stored in instance[index].

The only way I had it to work properly yet is with a switch statement but I want to avoid hard coding as much as possible.

```
switch (index) {
    case 0:
        ::attachInterrupt(pin, [] { instance[0]->tracker(); }, mode);
        break;
    case 1:
        ::attachInterrupt(pin, [] { instance[1]->tracker(); }, mode);
        break;
    ...
}
```

There must be a way to pass a reference of a specific static element of the array to the lambda function without using the switch statement, how could I achieve that?

Comment: Please show the actual signature that the callback must have (i.e. the type of the second argument to `attachInterrupt`).

Comment: More information about the callback function prototype and the function used to install it, please. If the callback allows you to provide a user parameter (usually a `void *`), the typical solution is to provide a `static` function that casts the user pointer to your class, and then invokes the member. Something like `void func(void * userarg) { ((myclass *)userarg)->memberfunc(); }`.

Comment: If the pass-through function is simple enough you might also consider a lambda (simply making the lambda the callback argument) (Note that to use a lambda as a C callback requires that you not capture any variables). [] (void * ptr) { (*(MyType*)ptr)(); }

Comment: That is an unfortunate callback function prototype or someone abusing some seriously archaic C. It looks like you can install one and only one callback handler function and will have to handle any further dispatch on your own inside that handler function.

Comment: Is the size of your `instance` array known at compile time? And is each of these `Actuator`s going to be registered as a callback?

Comment: @SoronelHaetir The callback doesn't have any argument

Comment: @sebrockm I use a fixed size array of instance right now because I have no choice since I need to hard code the lambda functions in a switch statement and yes I register all the actuators.

Comment: From your code above, it is not clear from where come the `index`. I don't understand why you would attach different callback to the same pin/mode. Please complete the question with missing information and even better provide MVCE.

Comment: @Phil1970 The `index` is incremented in the constructor and stored in the instance. The `pin` is a parameter of the constructor and different for each instance, it's also stored in the instance.

Comment: @VAlain If `pin` and `index` are stored in the instance, as you say, then you should write your code snippets accordingly, as Phil already asked you to do. In particular, I would expect to see `instance[0]->pin` rather than `pin` and `instance[0]->index` rather than `index` if both are stored in the instance. If you are still looking for a solution, you really should clarify on this as this appears to be rather important to be well understood by us in order to give you a good answer (as I experienced with my own answer).

Comment: @sebrockm The `switch` statement allow me to execute the registration at each instanciation so I get `index` and `pin` from the instance being instanciated and my snippet reflect the actual code.

Comment: @VAlain So you are saying that the `switch` is executed in the constructor of your `Actuator` class? This is the only way how I can make sense out of your description. If I still didn't understand you, **please update your code snippet to show where `pin`, `index`, and `mode` come from**.

Comment: Obviously, the code with static variable `actuator` won't work because you use a static variable which mean that there is only one instance of that variable and it will contains the last value that was set.

Comment: I don't see the purpose of the switch statement as it essentially only copy the value of index into an hard-coded constant index. If you need to pass that to the lambda, why not simply pass the copy of the index as an argument to the lambda? (i.e `[index]{ your code }`)

Comment: @Phil1970 I know it's not working with the static `actuator` variable, that's what I say in my question and I use the `switch` statement because as I also say in my question the caller function only support C-style callback which mean the capture list is not supported in the lambda.

Comment: From your other similar question, it look like the index and the pin are the same things. Do you have a consecutive range to cover with distinct functions (say pin 0 to pin 50) without any gap? Or would you like to register any function in that range provide there was a specialization? Do this code is performance sensitive? Is all the initialization done once? Do we need to unregister callbacks at some points? It the callback fixed for the application lifetime our can it change at some point? Is it possible to register more that one callback per pin? **Those details matters for best solution**

Answer (score 2):

If you know the number of callbacks you want to register at compile time, you could create your callbacks as template function:

```
template <size_t i>
static void callback()
{
    instance[i]->tracker();
}
```

Then you can use `std::make_index_sequence` and the unpacking syntax of variadic templates to register all at once:

```
template <size_t... ids>
void register_all_callbacks_impl(std::index_sequence<ids...>)
{
    // the (f(), 0) syntax calls a void function f but returns an int 0
    // with this trick you can leverage the unpacking syntax
    // to call void functions in an array initialization 
    int dummy[] = { (attachInterrupt(pin, &callback<ids>, mode), 0)... };
    (void)dummy; // omit "unused variable" warnings
}

constexpr size_t COUNT = ...;

void register_all_callbacks()
{
    register_all_callbacks_impl(std::make_index_sequence<COUNT>());
}
```

All you need to do now is initialize your `instance` array with size `COUNT` and call `register_all_callbacks()`.

Note: you need C++14 for `make_index_sequence`.

Comment: This says it is a c++11 version of make_index_sequence https://gist.github.com/jappa/62f30b6da5adea60bad3

Comment: @JerryJeremiah you are right, it is possible to implement it yourself in C++11. I've once done it myself back then :) But it is part of the standard library since C++14.

Comment: @sebrockm I use a fixed size array right now and it work well in my actual implementation with the switch statement but I want to be able to add more instances at runtime without having to change the source code.

Comment: @VAlain maybe you should mention this in your question, if this is your goal ;-)
do you have any upper limit of instances that you are not going to exceed? Then this technique could still work

Comment: @sebrockm I already say in my question that my actual implementation with the switch statement already work but I want to avoid the hard coding. Your technique involve hard coding the number of actuators but I tried it anyway out of curiosity and I have not made it to work. With your implementation each lambda is attached to the same pin from the last registered instance but each lambda need to be registered with it's own instance pin.

Comment: @VAlain I'm sorry, but from your question it was not obvious to me what exactly you meant by "hard coding". My solution involves no hard coding in so far that `COUNT` could be `10` or `1000000`, you always need only those few lines of code from my answer. I thought this was the issue that you were facing with your `switch` solution. Also, in your `switch` code snippet you are using the same pin all the time, too. So I think I am not to blame for doing the same in my solution :)

Comment: With tThis is some idea from my answer

Answer (score 0):

I would probably try something like

```
template<uint32_t pin, uint32_t mode> class callback
{
public:
    static void attach() { ::attachInterrupt(pin, &callback::tracker, mode); }

private:
    // Make specialization for each combination
    static void tracker();
}
```

Then to register callback, you would do:

```
callback<5, 3>::attach();
callback<7, 2>::attach();
```

If the mode is a constant dependant on the pin number, then you would use a static member of the callback class and then initialize a specific value for each class type.

```
const uint32_t callback<7>::mode_for_this_pin = 3; // maybe constexpr instead?
```

But as the question does not contains much details, it is hard to give a good solution.

We assume that it is impossible to know the pin when the callback is called so that it is up to the client to associate a specific function to each pin.

Alternatively, you could also add a `static std::function<void()> mfn` member to the class and then initialize it like that:

```
callback<7, 3>::mfn = [] { your code here };
```

This could be useful if the callback to execute depend on some conditions.

**There are no universal answer to your question as this is not directly supported by the language. The best solution depend on multiple factors that are not documented in your question.**

Obviously if the function for a specific pin is always the same, you could easily have a function `pin3_callback` or `pin3_mode2_callback` and do whatever appropriate in the implementation.

Other points that are not specified in the question when initialization should be done and if some cleanup is required.

I know that under windows, some assembler code was used in the past to generate unique function for cases where it was not possible to provide user data to the callback.